# set `history -r` in --init-file

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc

If I enter into my bash shell

```
touch $HOME/tmp
echo "last thing" >> $HOME/tmp
history -r $HOME/tmp
```

and then hit up-arrow, I see "last thing".

And if I paste the same lines in a script and source the script, then I get the same thing.

However, it won't work if I do

```
bash --init-file <(echo "history -r $HOME/tmp")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--init-file` is processed first and then the contents of `${HISTFILE:-$HOME/.bash_history}` is loaded as normal. If that file contains `$HISTSIZE` entries, as will usually be the case, the entry loaded by `history -r tmp` is pushed off the beginning of the history list and lost.

The following variants work for me (in 4.1.2 on CentOS):

```
bash --init-file <(echo history -r temp; echo HISTFILE=/dev/null)
# in new shell history contains only the line(s) from temp

bash --init-file <(echo history -r temp; echo let HISTSIZE+=100)
# in new shell history contains the line(s) from temp THEN .bash_history
```

Comment: Thank you! The `/dev/null` variant worked for me. The second one did not, but perhaps due to my particular .bashrc, which has multiple other history-related things going on.